# jQuery attr is not working

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have image in container and I have set width and height attributes for this image in CSS. But I need to add loading image and it is smaller than actual pictures that will be shown in container, so I need to change size of image while it is loading. But when I set width and height attributes, image is shown in size that is set in CSS.

```
$(img).attr("src", "loading.gif");
$(img).show();
$(img).attr("width", "100px");
$(img).attr("height", "100px");
```

Comment: Instead of assuming that a framework that MANY people use is broken (especially in such a key place as this), try to read up on what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: This is a good question, the title just needs to be edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing attributes with CSS:

```
$(img)
  .attr("src", "loading.gif")
  .css({width:100,height:100})
  .show();
```

Of course this assumes that `img` is actually representing an image:

```
var img = $("img.myImage");
```

If you don't have an image, you'll need to create one, and append it to the DOM:

```
$("<img>")
  .attr("src", "loading.gif")
  .css({width:100,height:100})
  .appendTo("body");
```

Comment: Ok it was my mistake, thanx for all answers!

Comment: @newbie: were you trying to *create* an image?

Answer (score 3):

Have you examined what the source will look like when you're done?

```
<img src="loading.gif" width="100px" height="100px" />
```

won't work.

```
<img src="loading.gif" width="100" height="100" />
```

will. So remove the `px` units =)

EDIT: As the other responders pointed out, it's better to use css. However, both of them forgot that in css you *do* need the units.

```
$(img).css({width: "100px"; height: "100px";});
```

Comment: Ha - I apparently don't have my units/not units down either =)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `attr("width")` etc to override CSS, use `css()`:

```
$(img).attr('src', 'loading.gif').show().css({ width: 100, height: 100 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try adjusting the style attributes instead, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170624/javascript-image-resize)?

Answer (score 0):

The only unit for the `width` and `height` attributes is a percentage (`…%`). [Values without that unit are always pixels.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-length) So try this:

```
$(img).attr("width", "100");
$(img).attr("height", "100");
```