# Resizing images uploaded using GWT File upload

Tags: image, gwt, resize

I have a mobile app where users can upload JPGs but I want to limit the size of the image before sending it to my GAE blobstore.  I don't want to have to force a user to resize the image they want to upload but rather just do it on the fly. Anyone got a way to do this without distorting the image?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to do it and no third party library in gwt yet for this.

### Option 1

The best you can try is for GWT wrappers over html5 apis . You can track this on another stackoverflow question [Image resizing client-side with javascript before upload to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434458/image-resizing-client-side-with-javascript-before-upload-to-the-server)

### Option 2

Upload and process on server side before pushing to GAE blobstore.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct blobstores maximum file size is around 2Gb. And you can send around 1Mb of data in one request of GAE blobstore service.

There is an app called [AppImage](https://github.com/benjaminpearson/gae-web-services/blob/master/README) that divides the file into smaller pieces. For more info on that click the below link

[Large Image Resizing for Google App Engine](http://developinginthedark.com/posts/large-image-resizing-for-google-app-engine)

***This is just a thought :*** why do you want to upload it through GAE as you can directly upload it to blobstore unless it **greater the 2Gb !!!!**

Comment: My app will hopefully have lots of small images and I don't want to gobble up my free datastore space with just a handful of images. Also I don't want users having to download files any bigger than a couple of KB for performance reasons

Comment: The trade off is between client side performance and code complexity vs server side bandwidth and server side cpu usage.