# Shrink image before uploading with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, shrink

I'm writing a cross-platform mobile application using phonegap,
and i have a file-upload input for image uploading of single images.

The problem is that most pictures being uploaded are ones taken using the mobile phone which are around 4MB in size.

I want to shrink those images dramatically, as i don't need them in high quality at all.

Also, i need them converted to base64 and not in real image file. (That i already have using FileReader)

Any ideas how to achieve this? Maybe using canvas or something?

**Update:**
here is what i have so far:

```
function shrink() {
    var self = this;

    var reader = new FileReader(); // init a file reader
    var file = $('#file-input').prop('files')[0]; // get file from input

    reader.onloadend = function() {

        // shrink image
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = reader.result;

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 300);
        var shrinked = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        console.log(shrinked);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file); // convert file to base64*/
}
```

but all i get is a black image
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434458/image-resizing-client-side-with-javascript-before-upload-to-the-server (which leads to http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/how-to-develop-a-html5-image-uploader/)

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.

The problem was that i wasn't waiting for the image to fully load before drawing it.

once i added

```
image.onload = function() {

}
```

and ran everything inside it works.

Comment: where was this in relation to the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old thread, but I had the same question about where to place the "on load" and this worked for me...

```
       navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageURI) {
           console.log("*** capture success. uri length...", imageURI.length);            
           var image = document.createElement('img');
           image.onload = function() {
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 300);
                var shrunk = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                console.log(shrunk);
                // used shrunk here
            }
            image.src = imageURI; // triggers the onload
       }
```

pat