# issue loading images on HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, canvas

So far I have a function next which is supposed to get a the time(just the hours) which then compares the hours in an if statement to load the correct clock into the imageURLs[] array. As far as I can tell this works fine. Then running the loadAllimages() function it should load the image into the array imgs[]. Then it should draw the images in the method start(). I did it in this way because the pill image is on top of the clock and I needed it to load correctly. The problem is the loadAllimages() function is not working and i can't figure out why. So far all i can tell is it not pushing it on the array imgs[] because at the start of the start() function imgs.length is 0.

```
function next(){
var currentdate = new Date();
var datetime = currentdate.getHours();
var imageURLs=[];
var imagesOK=0;
var imgs=[];
if(datetime==1||datetime==13){
imageURLs.push("clock/clock1.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==2||datetime==14){
imageURLs.push("clock/clock2.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==3||datetime==15){
imageURLs.push("clock/clock3.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==4||datetime==16){
imageURLs.push("clock/clock4.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==5||datetime==17){
imageURLs.push("clock/clock5.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==6||datetime==18){
imageURLs.push("clock/clock6.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==7||datetime==19){
imageURLs.push("clock/clock7.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==8||datetime==20){
imageURLs.push("clock/clock8.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==9||datetime==21){
imageURLs.push("clock/clock9.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==10||datetime==22){
imageURLs.push("clock/clock10.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==11||datetime==23){
imageURLs.push("clock/clock11.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==0||datetime==12){
imageURLs.push("clock/clock12.png");
imageURLs.push("clock/pill.png");
}

loadAllImages();

function loadAllImages(){

    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imgs.push(img);
        };
    } 
    if(i==imageURLs.length){
    start();
    }

}

function start(){
    // the imgs[] array holds your fully loaded images
    for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
    if(i==0){
        canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 600,100);
        }
        else{
        canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 740, 240 );
        }
    }
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

}
}
```

Comment: You might find my [YAIL image loader](http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/11/yail-yet-another-image-loader-for-javascript/) useful as an alternative. Also this has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524444/how-to-load-images-from-json-object-on-canvas-image/17527381#17527381).

Answer (score 0):

The loading happens asynchronously, not immediately. You should change your code to

```
imgs.push(img);
if (imgs.length == imageURLs.length) start();
```

inside the `onload` handler.

Note however that's possible that the order in the `imgs` array will not be the same as the order in the `imageURLs` array.

IMO a cleaner approach would be however to put the images immediately in the list and just incrementing a counter when the load completes:

```
function loadAllImages(){
    var count = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            if (++count == imageURLs.length) start();
        };
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
        imgs.push(img);
    }
}
```

this way the order in which the images are in the array is the order in the `imageURLs` array.

Comment: This is still not working even with your code. I'm not really sure where its going wrong. Neither image is loading. The code is definitely reaching past the imgs.push(img) line as I tested this by putting an alert after it.

Comment: If one of the images doesn't load correctly (e.g. the url is wrong) `start` is not going to be called.

Comment: i've check the urls very carefully and i dont think they're wrong.