# How to resize image before to upload to blostore (resizing from client, but if not possible, doing it from server)

Tags: gwt, upload, blobstore

I am using GWT and the blobstore (GAE). The client uploads an image but I would like to resize this image (w:77px, h:110px) before to store it in the blobstore. I have followed this tutorial :

> http://ikaisays.com/2010/09/08/gwt-blobstore-the-new-high-performance-image-serving-api-and-cute-dogs-on-office-chairs/

but it does not do what I want...(moreover, the scaling is done after obtaining the blob key, and I would like to store the image with the good dimentions...).

I will use anything usefull (html 5 file api, gwt upload wrapper, or server side resizing)... but I have no idea how to resize the image coming from a uploader (any code, explication or link to help please).

Thanks you,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434458/image-resizing-client-side-with-javascript-before-upload-to-the-server

Comment: Yep, with javascript, everything already exists, but I would prefer a solution in JAVA, with GWT if possible...If not, I will try to use JS. Moreover, I would like a portative solution (I do not know if Mozilla solution is portative in all browser)