# angularjs compress image before upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, file-upload, compression

I'm buliding a web site for mobile devices, that uses angular-file-upload.min.js for uploading images from a mobile device image library.

html code:

```
<div>
    <div class="rating-camera-icon">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file" ng-file-
         select="onFileSelect($files)">
    </div>
    <img ng-show="fileName" ng-src="server/{{fileName}}" width="40"
     style="margin-left:10px">
</div>
```

code:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
            var file = $files[i];
            if (!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                // this file is not an image.
            };
            $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
                url: BASE_URL + 'upload.php',
                data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
                file: file
            }).progress(function(evt) {
                    // console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                    // $scope.fileProgress = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100.0;
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // file is uploaded successfully
                    $scope.fileName = data;
                });
        }
    };
```

The upload is very slow in mobile devices. How can I compress the file?

Comment: if you are not using native app you cannot compress a file also most of the images like jpg are already compressed as far as I know there is nothing you can do.

Comment: If you are looking for image manipulation prior to uploading this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434458/image-resizing-client-side-with-javascript-before-upload-to-the-server

Answer (score 3):

Stringifying the image into a base-64 text format is all fine and well, but it will take a small amount of time and certainly does not compress it. In fact it will likely be noticeably larger than the raw image.  Unfortunately your browser will also not gzip an uploads.  They can of course handle gzipped downloads. You could certainly try to do a gzip of the text itself using some pure JS solution.  Looking on github you can find such things - https://github.com/beatgammit/gzip-js  However, that will take some time as well and there is no guarantee that the compressed text version of the image is any smaller than the raw JPEG you attach.

A native mobile app might decide to use some native code JPEG or PNG optimization before sending (basically resample the image) if appropriate, but doing this out in JavaScript seems potentially problematic at this point in time.  Given Atwood's law (of writing everything eventually in JavaScript) it certainly could be done but at this point in mid-2014 it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to store the image on a canvas, then convert to data64 and then upload the data string. 
I made kind of this in a POC, theres a bug in ios regarding large images as the one you could take with the camera when in canvas, but the overal works nice... something like;

```
file = files[0];
try {
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
      imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  showPicture.src = imgURL;
  imgBlobToStore = imgURL;
  if(AppData.supports_html5_storage()) {      
    var canvas = document.getElementById('storingCanvas') ,
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        img = new Image(),
        convertedFile;
    img.src = imgBlobToStore;
    img.onload = function () {    
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height= img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0,img.width, img.height);
        convertedFile = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); //or png
        //replace with angular storage here
        localStorage.setItem( $('.pic').attr('id'), convertedFile);
    };
  }, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries that do this for you on the client side.

- https://github.com/oukan/angular-image-compress
- https://github.com/sammychl/ng-image-compress
- http://angularscript.com/client-side-image-compress-directive-with-angular/

Answer (score -4):

As an alternative to a programmatic solution - if your image is being created by the device camera for upload, then why not simply change the resolution of the camera. The smallest resolution may be 10x smaller than the largest, and this may be suitable for many situations.