# Uploading an image cropped using a cropper.js plugin

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, html5-canvas

I have used [cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) plugin in my application to crop images. I am able to crop the images. Now I am trying to upload the images instead of downloading them.
I have updated the the modal window that shows the cropped image as follows:

```
<!-- Show the cropped image in modal -->
<div class="modal fade docs-cropped" id="getCroppedCanvasModal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="getCroppedCanvasTitle" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="getCroppedCanvasTitle">Cropped</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" style = "float: left;">Close</button>
       <form class="form-inline" id="croperImgForm" role="form" method="post" action="${rc.getContextPath()}/module/simplewebcontent/save-image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Save Image
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">Save Thumbnail
        </label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="svImg" style = "margin-left: 10px;">Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Here I have added a form in the bottom with option to Save the image. I am trying to use the following script to save the form:

```
$("#svImg").click( function()
    {
    alert('button clicked');
    $("#croperImgForm").submit(function(e)
    {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax(
        {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        dataType : "html",
        success:function(htmlData) 
        {

        },
        error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
            console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
            console.log( "Status: " + status );
            console.dir( xhr );
        },
    });

        e.preventDefault(); 
        e.unbind();
    });
});
```

Now I found from the docs that I should use the following code to save the image:

```
// Upload cropped image to server if the browser supports `canvas.toBlob`
$().cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob) {
  var formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('croppedImage', blob);

  $.ajax('/path/to/upload', {
    method: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function () {
      console.log('Upload success');
    },
    error: function () {
      console.log('Upload error');
    }
  });
});
```

But I am not sure how to use this code as a part of the form submission which I am trying to implement as an ajax call.

Also I use Spring mvc, so what would be the parameters in the controller method in case of this image upload.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I crop the image at client side using jcrop and upload it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651017/how-should-i-crop-the-image-at-client-side-using-jcrop-and-upload-it)

Comment: here is a complete tutorial http://howsolve.com/image-crop-with-laravel54-intervention-and-cropperjs-jquery/

Answer (score 11):

Though this question was asked long back, still I am sharing a link to the solution I just posted in context to someone else's problem.

I hope it will help someone found on this page. ( Like I landed and found no solution )
[Crop image using Cropper.js, then upload (or display) the cropped image.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750612/crop-image-using-coordinates/#answer-38752414)

Answer (score 5):

In you code above, remember Canvas function `toBlob` accepts 3 params (as per [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Syntax)):

- `callback`
- `mimeType` e.g. `image/jpg`
- `quality` e.g `90`

So in your function you can include the `mimeType` and `quality` options. Also in the append line include a thirds parameter for filename (with same extension)

```
canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  
  /* Add blob and file name */
  formData.append('croppedImage', blob, 'file.jpg');

  $.ajax('/path/to/upload', {
    method: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function () {
      console.log('Upload success');
    },
    error: function () {
      console.log('Upload error');
    }
  });

/* This is the important part */
}, 'image/jpeg', 0.9);
```

Answer (score 0):

[github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperj Api Doc](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#getcroppedcanvasoptions) for Server Upload as formData and Image src tag definition.

and watch out the below paragraph of getCroppedCanvas():

> After then, you can display the canvas as an image directly, or use HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL to get a Data URL, or use HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob to get a blob and upload it to server with FormData if the browser supports these APIs.