# Canvas to blob on Edge

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, blob, microsoft-edge

Getting exception on Microsoft Edge browser when trying to convert Html canvas element to blob. Everything works great on normal browsers.
Exception:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'toBlob'

Html snippet:

```
<canvas id="cnv" width="640px" height="520px" style="display: none"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var files[];
var canvas = document.getElementById('cnv');
canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {            
        files.push(blob);
         }
    }, 'image/jpeg', 1);
```

I get this exception right when I call `toBlob` method. Are there any ways to teach Edge blob converting? 
I am using :

> Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This small polyfill taken [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) must help [see jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/IsArlekin/obv5j64f/7/)

```
if (!HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob) {
   Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toBlob', {
     value: function (callback, type, quality) {
       var canvas = this;
       setTimeout(function() {
         var binStr = atob( canvas.toDataURL(type, quality).split(',')[1] ),
         len = binStr.length,
         arr = new Uint8Array(len);

         for (var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
            arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
         }

         callback( new Blob( [arr], {type: type || 'image/png'} ) );
       });
     }
  });
}
```

This could help as well [github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob)

Answer (score 0):

If you use **webpack** and **ES6** then [install the package](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob) via npm

```
npm install blueimp-canvas-to-blob
```

Then import the package like so

```
import "blueimp-canvas-to-blob/js/canvas-to-blob";
```