# Internal Server Error when posting image via jquery, ajax and django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, html

I'm trying to post a cropped image via Jquery and ajax.
I've been following the solution to this question [crop image using coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750612/crop-image-using-coordinates/#answer-38752414), however I've had no luck in receiving the image on Django's end, despite the CSRF token and image being handled by the ajax request fine.

I haven't done anything in my views.py, just attempted to print request.FILES and request.POST to see if anything got returned but no luck. Not sure how or if I should be handling that a different way.

**JS**

```
  function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result)
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  setTimeout(initCropper,1000);
}
```

}

```
function initCropper() {
    console.log("initializing")
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
      aspectRatio: 16/9,
      viewMode: 1,
      autoCropArea: 0.8,
      cropBoxResizable: false,
      minCropBoxWidth: 640,
      minCropBoxHeight: 360,
      minContainerWidth: 720,
      minContainerHeight: 405,
      crop: function(e) {
        console.log(e.detail.x);
        console.log(e.detail.y);
      }
    });
document.getElementById('crop_button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var imgurl = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = imgurl;

  cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function(blob){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('croppedImage', blob);
    formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{csrf_token}}')

    $.ajax({
      url: '/campaigns/create/',
      method:"POST",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
      success: function () {
        console.log("Upload success");
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log('Upload error')
      }
    });
  });

})
```

};

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9">
                                      <input type="file" name="inputImage" id="inputImage" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
                                      <div class="image_container">
                                        <img id="image" src="#" alt="your image"/>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button id="crop_button">Crop</button>
```

**ERROR**

```
....
[16/Dec/2018 14:08:26] "POST /campaigns/create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
[16/Dec/2018 14:08:26] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('------ 
WebKitFormBoundarycvWRqqCDKW5sPfBT')
[16/Dec/2018 14:08:26] "------WebKitFormBoundarycvWRqqCDKW5sPfBT" 400 -
```

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly setting the `contentType` property to  `multipart/form-data` but that's missing the boundary string which is required for `multipart/form-data` requests. Django would then not understand how to parse the request body.

Try setting `contentType` to `false` which will instruct JQuery not to set the `Content-Type` header.

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  contentType: false,
```