# Jcrop-croppped image save into database in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jcrop

I am using Jcrop plugin to crop an image when we browse the image. (By SO reference [How should I crop the image at client side using jcrop and upload it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651017/how-should-i-crop-the-image-at-client-side-using-jcrop-and-upload-it) ). Now I can crop the image. But could not able to save the cropped image, original image only saved. I get the params in terminal like,

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BsraH8EHNbcut/CVhvp6oDEXP2eL2NczSwMhabo02W6WO3rPF+3SNnl8m8jIS588UtpuDOeeID90Skv8AkljLQ==", "recipient_type_pa"=>"PA", "message"=>{"title"=>"Attachment Check", "description"=>"test", "attachment"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fcb526150b0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170526-10666-8e2siv.png>, @original_filename="upload.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message[attachment]\"; filename=\"upload.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "expire_date"=>"26-05-2017"}, "canvascontent"=>"data:image/png;base64,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", "destination_type_sms"=>"SMS"}
```

How to save the cropped image into database ?

Comment: did you use paperclip gem?

Comment: if yes than try this https://github.com/rsantamaria/papercrop

Comment: I am using the gems carrierwave and mini_magick

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay the param get by Base64 encryption.