# Resize an image before uploading it to firebase

Tags: firebase, imagemagick, firebase-storage

Firebase storage looks very cool and easy to use, but I'm wondering if there's a way to resize an image before uploading it to Firebase Storage, e.g., run a proccess using ImageMagick in a server and then run the uploading process using Firebase SDK but I notice there aren't storage functions for Firebase SDK Server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use Firebase Storage + [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) to upload an image, resize the image (using ImageMagick or similar), and write it back to Firebase Storage.

I have an example using these together [here](https://github.com/mcdonamp/flaming-specs) (though I trigger the [Cloud Vision API](http://cloud.google.com/vision), rather than an image resizer).

A quick side note: Firebase Storage doesn't have a Node.js client, instead we recommend using the [GCloud-Node](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node) library.

Comment: I was thinking the same but I wasn't sure, would be awesome to use the gcloud-golang instead of node for this.

Comment: You can always set up Object Change Notifications (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) + a Go Google App Engine app (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/) to do this :)

Answer (score 7):

### Resize using JavaScript Client-Side-Processing

We're using **JavaScript resizing**, which uses clients device processing power to resize the image, and works GREAT, saving us space and money, saving the netwrok unnecesary bandwidth, and saving the client a bunch of time and also money in most mobile cases.

The original script we are using **[came from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31669706/1920145)**, and the procedure to use it is as simple as this:

```
<input type="file" id="select">
<img id="preview">
<script>
document.getElementById('select').onchange = function(evt) {
    ImageTools.resize(this.files[0], {
        width: 320, // maximum width
        height: 240 // maximum height
    }, function(blob, didItResize) {
        // didItResize will be true if it managed to resize it, otherwise false (and will return the original file as 'blob')
        document.getElementById('preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // you can also now upload this blob using an XHR.
    });
};
</script>
```

**I believe that guy (dcollien) deserves a LOT of merit, so I would recommend you to vote his answer up.**

Comment: How do you then upload this blob to firebase? I get an error: Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.

How do you go from window.URL.createObjectURL(blob) to something that can be .put() to firebase?

Comment: according to firebase docs, You should be able to upload blob's sameways as files:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file
As I can recall, the final functions of my implementations accept both.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Firebase Storage + the official Firebase `Resize Image` extension:
https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-storage-resize-images. The downside here is that "*To install an extension, your project must be on the Blaze (pay as you go) plan*". Bc basically what it will do is spin up a Firebase Function App for you, and it'll get triggered every time you upload a file to the path you specify. You can configure things like the desired size as well as the format or if you want to keep a copy of the original file or not.  Good thing you won't need to worry about the underlying implementation.