# Post HTML and JavaScript data to php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

i have a form with one file input and a submit button, The action attribute of the form set to 'upload.php' where i have my php script to rename the file and save it to a specific folder, But also i need some javascript variables for resizing and cropping the uploaded image.
What is the best way to send them both at the same time to be used by php script.

Thanks you very much..

this is javascript code:

```
    $('.upload_form').submit(function(){
  var crop_position_top = $('.crop_div').position().top;
  var crop_position_left = $('.crop_div').position().left;
  var img_position_top = $('.upload_preview').position().top;
  var img_position_left = $('.upload_preview').position().left;

  var crop_start_x = img_position_left - crop_position_left;
  var crop_start_y = img_position_top - crop_position_top;

  var crop_tool_width = $('.crop_div').width();
  var crop_tool_height = $('.crop_div').height();

  var img_name = $('.upload_img_input').val();
  $.post("upload.php", {start_x: crop_start_x, start_y: crop_start_y, crop_width: crop_tool_width, crop_height:crop_tool_height});

});
```

Comment: Will you please provide some example code to investigate this issue ?

Comment: Please provide a sample code to test

Comment: May be below link will help you out 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434458/image-resizing-client-side-with-javascript-before-upload-to-the-server

Comment: try it http://www.webmotionuk.com/jquery-image-upload-and-crop-for-php/

Comment: @AnkitDoshi that's my js code i used, when i try to echo the posted js values it says Undefined indexes, while the file is posted successfully.

Comment: @SanketR that's my js code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add hidden input such as

And you can dynamically allocate value using javascript based on your action