# How to reduce bandwidth by reducing an image size on the client side prior to uplaod

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

SO I have an html form which can accept the users camera input or oother file.
The problem I have ios that the images and many MB in size.  On output (part of a written report) the images only have to be 800x600max in size.  Many images may be uploaded as part of process the user must go through.

My question is how can I use an

```
 <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
```

And then resize it on the client side AND swap the orginal image for the resized on in the form ready for form submission.

I have read much but cannot see any direct answers to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image resizing client-side with javascript before upload to the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434458/image-resizing-client-side-with-javascript-before-upload-to-the-server)

Comment: You may also want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303690/resizing-an-image-in-an-html5-canvas