# Image size change before upload to server

Tags: javascript, php, image, upload, resize

I want to upload an image from website to server, but I need to reduce image size to save user time ( if used a mobile website ).
Let say, 5-6 MB pic must become <1MB.
Ask for help, spend 4 days in googling - zero result.
I believe it must by a js part and PHP on server.

Comment: Yes it would have to be client-side; with PHP you'd have to upload the large file before it was resized since it runs on the server, this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434458/image-resizing-client-side-with-javascript-before-upload-to-the-server