# How to resize user uploaded image in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I want to resize user uploaded images and get a thumbnail and other image dimensions. I use this code to receive uploaded images

```
   var files = fileInput.files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var imageType = /image.*/;
    if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
        continue;
    }
    var img = document.getElementById("thumbnil");
    img.file = file;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
        return function(e) {
            aImg.src = e.target.result;
        };
    })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

I want the uploaded image be resized to 
thumbnail size to 136 × 136 and single image size to 454 × 527 so that I can save them to the database. How can I adjust the code to resize the image?

Comment: Use a canvas element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image resizing client-side with JavaScript before upload to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434458/image-resizing-client-side-with-javascript-before-upload-to-the-server)

Comment: @Musa could you give a detailed example of how to use the `canvas` element? Otherwise your comment will not help the question asker to find a solution.

Comment: @SaschaM78 no, my comment is sufficient for a can i have teh codez question

Comment: @SaschaM78, why because people need to be spoon fed?