# Rails 5.2 ActiveStorage crop attachment before upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variant, rails-activestorage

I am able to resize the `avatar` in the `view` using

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100")
```

But I am wondering if there is a way to resize it before actually uploading the avatar.

When I run the same line in my `controller`, I get this error:

```
undefined method `variant' for # <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fcecfdac190>
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to resize before uploading you can use HTML5 canvas element + Javascript to do the desired processing and then send the image to the server.

[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434458/image-resizing-client-side-with-javascript-before-upload-to-the-server) for more details.