# UIWebView and scaling images - inconsistent results?

Tags: objective-c, css, ios, html, uiwebview

I have the following bit of HTML that I send - as part of a larger html document - to a UIWebView:

```
<img src="imagename.png" style="height: 20%; width: 20%;">
```

Sometimes, the image appears properly scaled. Sometimes, it appears scaled only in one direction, with the other being 100%. Sometimes, it appears with the image at original size in both directions. I cannot understand why the results are inconsistent. Perhaps I am scaling improperly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question. I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170624/javascript-image-size) here on this site.

To correct, I did this:

```
<img src="image.png" style="height: 20%; width: auto;">
```