# How to force image resize and keep aspect ratio?

Tags: css, image, aspect-ratio

I am working with images, and I ran into a problem with aspect ratios.

```html
<img src="big_image.jpg" width="900" height="600" alt="" />
```

As you can see, `height` and `width` are already specified. I added a CSS rule for images:

```css
img {
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

But for `big_image.jpg`, I receive `width=500` and `height=600`. How do I set images to be re-sized, whilst keeping their aspect ratios.

Answer (score 1077, accepted):

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width:230px;
  max-height:95px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>This image is originally 400x400 pixels, but should get resized by the CSS:</p>
<img width="400" height="400" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEEkn.png">
```

This will make image shrink if it's too big for specified area (as downside, it will not enlarge image).

Comment: Is there a version of this that will enlarge images to fit their container also? I've tried the max-width/max-height as numbers with width/height as auto, but as setec said above, it will not enlarge the image. I've tried using min-width/min-height also. I just can't get the combination right. I simply want that whatever image I have to put into this container, it will display at it's maximum size possible without changing aspect ratio regardless of whether that involves shrinking or growing the image to achieve that.

Comment: @Dee2000 i've tried all what you said too without result, looks like it's not possible with pure css (but have't yet tried css3). Finally come to use of solution described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/170636/753621, but it requires JS.

Comment: I saw that one too, it didn't help me. I've now built a JS function to figure out what the right size is. Normally that would have been my default goto method, but I've been trying to use CSS more where possible.

Comment: I tested the code in three browsers: Firefox, Chrome and IE11. Works perfect so far. CSS workaround is always preferred over JavaScript. Great solution... nice and easy!

Comment: Seems that display: block is no more needed.

Comment: Note that the question was about an `<img>` that itself includes a width and height and I think that means you need to use `!important` to circumvent the tag width/height info.

Comment: @AlexisWilke CSS rules override html attributes. `!important` is not needed.

Comment: @ahnbizcad if this isn't working make sure your IMG has an SRC. If the IMG is given a background-image via a class this may not work.

Comment: Using it on Chrome, not working for me, even with !important

Comment: It worked for me with just 'max-width' css3 property.

Comment: I don't know why people are commenting that `display: block;` is necessary, it isn't! Try experimenting with the snippet and see.

Comment: If it isn't working, try checking the computed styles and see if a CSS rule contradicts what you expected to see. This solution works, thanks!

Comment: I had it in a flex context with a very wide sibling and this caused the image to be shown distorted. Wrapping the `<img>` tag in an element with `display: block` fixed it.

Comment: Add `margin: auto;` if you want it centered in it's container

Comment: please note this will cause a problem with Google CLS - Cumulative Layout Shift - the size of the image and thus size of the block reserved for image to be painted in is different than CSS dimensions, and this will cause the shift :( is there a way how to work around this?

Comment: @Dee2000 use [object-fit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39039206/4854931). You can set height in width in px if you need.

Comment: Thanks @Alex78191, that page I was working on 8 years ago is almost finished, I'll try that :-)
Just kidding, I don't even remember what that was for now.

Comment: This didn't work for me either. The object-fit one below did however

Comment: @Dee2000 have you ever found a way with pure css?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for width/heights in `%` or `vh/vw`. The CSS `object-fit:contain;` seems to be much better

Answer (score 711):

Here's a solution:

```
object-fit: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 250px;
```

You can adjust the width and height to fit your needs, and the object-fit property will do the cropping for you.

More information about the possible values for the `object-fit` property and a compatibility table are available here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: Not viable on SAMSUNG Signage Display WebApps.

Comment: You can also use `object-fit: contain` and specify a width or height!

Comment: Note that this is not supported on ie
https://caniuse.com/object-fit

Comment: As of now it has 97.96% browser support

Answer (score 302):

**The solutions below will allow scaling up and scaling down of the image**, depending on the parent box width.

All images have a parent container with a fixed width *for demonstration purposes only*. In production, this will be the width of the parent box.

## Best Practice (2018):

This solution tells the browser to render the image with max available width and adjust the height as a percentage of that width.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>This image is originally 400x400 pixels, but should get resized by the CSS:</p>
<div class="parent">
  <img width="400" height="400" src="https://place-hold.it/400x400">
</div>
```

## Fancier Solution:

With the fancier solution, you'll be able to crop the image regardless of its size and add a background color to compensate for the cropping.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 34.37% 0 0 0; /* 34.37% = 100 / (w / h) = 100 / (640 / 220) */
}

.container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>This image is originally 640x220, but should get resized by the CSS:</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <img width="640" height="220" src="https://place-hold.it/640x220">
  </div>
</div>
```

For the line specifying padding, you need to calculate the aspect ratio of the image, for example:

```
640px (w) = 100%
220px (h) = ?

640/220 = 2.909
100/2.909 = 34.37%
```

So, top padding = 34.37%.

Comment: I don't get it. I've loaded full HD images with both this and the accepted answer's solution. Is it really being scaled becasue I can't tell (tested on chrome and IE10+)

Comment: I love how standardization organizations were in a meeting once and all agreed: this should be the way people are going to achieve the desired result.

Comment: 2018 solution is bad, when the parent has width/height ratio smaller than the image width/height ratio, the image end up stretched badly.

Comment: @izzulmakin How about a codepen so I can see what you're talking about?

Comment: Neither of these work for me to upscale the image and keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: @Mär please post your code in a CodePen so I can help you out :)

Comment: That won't make too much sense. It's a 15k lines of code web architecture. The specific code you posted will result in correct scaling for images that have lower aspect ratios than that of their parent container, but will not work if it is vice versa, resulting in stretching. I was specifically looking for a dynamic approach, as prior I do not know DIV size or image dimensions. 

In the end I solved this by preloading the image, calculating the aspect ratio, comparing it versus the aspect ratio of the area and then apply the proper CSS style.

Comment: You can try it yourself though, if you like. Take an image that has a *lower* aspect ratio than the container it is placed in (IMG in DIV) and apply your code selecting *width: 100%*. The result should be a stretched image.

Comment: You lost me at position: absolute

Comment: I used width:auto for the parent.

Comment: @Madeo please create a CodePen to describe your issue.

On another note... I'm thankful for all the comments that made these snippets better but you need to invest some time explaining what you're trying to achive in order for me to be able to help.

Comment: Your math is a bit roundabout: since you just want `h` as a percentage of `w`, then instead of a chain of divisions, you can just do `100 * h / w`. Thus `100 * 220 / 640 = 34.37`.

Comment: @Théophile Thanks for the comment. It was meant to be informative and easy to follow along.

Comment: The fancier solution doesn't scale images up. Here's a demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/edmjgs58/

Comment: This didn't work for me in when the parent has display: flex... but only in Safari. Adding align-items: start fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! The fancier solution worked in my case. 
Also loved the calculation explained for padding.

Answer (score 102):

Very similar to some answers here, but in my case I had images that  sometimes were taller, sometimes larger.

This style worked like a charm to make sure that all images use all available space, keep the ratio and not cuts:

```
.img {
   object-fit: contain;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: `object-fit` works for me does it work in all browser ?

Comment: Is `.img` a class on the parent or the image? Could you make a jsfiddle with example for both portrait and landscape images?

Comment: Upvoted because it's the first to mention `object-fit: contain`. In my experience, all that's necessary is that plus either a height or width.

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian it's in the image `<img>`

Comment: This is great when your width changes like in a responsive grid!

Answer (score 77):

The background-size property is ie>=9 only, but if that is fine with you, you can use a div with `background-image` and set `background-size: contain`:

```
div.image{
    background-image: url("your/url/here");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Now you can just set your div size to whatever you want and not only will the image keep its aspect ratio it will also be centralized both vertically and horizontally within the div. Just don't forget to set the sizes on the css since divs don't have the width/height attribute on the tag itself.

This approach is different than setecs answer, using this the image area will be constant and defined by you (leaving empty spaces either horizontally or vertically depending on the div size and image aspect ratio), while setecs answer will get you a box that exactly the size of the scaled image (without empty spaces).

Edit:
According to the [MDN background-size documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) you can simulate the background-size property in IE8 using a proprietary filter declaration:

> Though Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support the background-size property, it is possible to emulate some of its functionality using the non-standard -ms-filter function:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='path_relative_to_the_HTML_file', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks! Also note that you can replace 'contain' by 'cover' if you want to fill the div completely and crop extra pixels that doesn't fit the ratio

Comment: While this is a correct answer programmatically, if an image "matters" this way you have no img attributes so you are killing SEO.

Answer (score 31):

Remove the "height" property.

```
<img src="big_image.jpg" width="900" alt=""/>
```

By specifying both you are changing the aspect ratio of the image. Just setting one will resize but preserve the aspect ratio.

Optionally, to restrict oversizings:

```
<img src="big_image.jpg" width="900" alt="" style="max-width:500px; height:auto; max-height:600px;"/>
```

Comment: i can't do it to all images - there are many images already placed in many html files

Comment: Ok. try img {max-width:500px; height:auto; max-height:600px;}

Comment: Useful information like that comment should be added to your post. That way we can immediately see what you've come up with.

Comment: The downside of omitting the `height` attribute in the `img` tag is that the browser cannot calculate how much space the image will take up before downloading the image. This make the page slower to render and it can lead to more "jumping".

Answer (score 31):

[Firefox 71+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/71) (2019-12-03) and [Chrome 79+](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5695266130755584) (2019-12-10) support internal [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Performance/Multimedia#rendering_strategy_preventing_jank_when_loading_images) of the `width` and `height` HTML attributes of the `IMG` element to the new [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) CSS property.

The calculated aspect ratio is used to reserve space for the image until it is loaded, and as long as the calculated aspect ratio is equal to the actual aspect ratio of the image, page “jump” is prevented after loading the image.

For this to work, one of the two image dimensions must be overridden via CSS to the `auto` value:

```
IMG {max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

```
<img src="example.png" width="1280" height="720" alt="Example" />
```

In the example, the aspect ratio of 16:9 (1280:720) is maintained even if the image is not yet loaded and the effective image width is less than 1280 as a result of `max-width: 100%`.

See also the related Firefox [bug 392261](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392261).

Comment: From all noise, this is the correct answer for most of people.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a solution :

```
img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

This will make sure the image always covers the entire parent (scaling down and up) and keeps the same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 14):

Just add this to your css, It will automaticly shrink and expand with keeping the original ratio.

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is the same answer as [setec's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17183996/247696), except using `100%` instead of a specific pixel value.

Comment: `display: block;` is unnecessary.

Comment: That's perfect and works with images of any size and proportion

Answer (score 14):

This is mental. Use the scale-down property - it explains itself.

Inline styling:

```
<img src='/nic-cage.png' style={{ maxWidth: '50%', objectFit: 'scale-down' }} />
```

This will stop flex from stretching it. In this case, the image would go to 50% of the width of its parent container and the height would scale down to match.

Keep it simple.

Answer (score 14):

### Just replace the `height` attribute by the `aspect-ratio` attribute.

```css
img {
  max-width: 500px;
  aspect-ratio: 900 / 600;
}
```

```html
<img src="big_image.png" width="900"/>
```

The `aspect-ratio` attribute is not necessary, but prevent image layout shifts.

Comment: The `height` and `width` attributes are not there only for display purposes but also for performance: they tell the browser what is the size of the original image. I downvoted for this reason: removing one of these attributes shouldn’t be an appropriate solution.

Comment: Perfectly accepted by Chrome Lighthouse

Comment: @bfontaine if you remove the height attribute, the browser is still able to get the size of the original image, by dividing the width by the aspect-ratio. So, I believe the performance problem is solved by including the "aspect-ratio" attribute as shown in my code snippet.

Comment: @DanielBarral 1- there’s no guarantee that the aspect-ratio declared in CSS is the same as the original one. 2- the height/width attribute are parsed by the browser very early when it loads the page, before fetching the image URL. The CSS is loaded/parsed later.

Answer (score 9):

To maintain a responsive image while still enforcing the image to have a certain aspect ratio you can do the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="ratio2-1">
   <img src="../image.png" alt="image">
</div>
```

And SCSS:

```
.ratio2-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;

  &:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 50%; // ratio 2:1
  }

  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

This can be used to enforce a certain aspect ratio, regardless of the size of the image that authors upload.

Thanks to @Kseso at  http://codepen.io/Kseso/pen/bfdhg. Check this URL for more ratios and a working example.

Comment: I like this as it works with circles / `border-radius`. But unfortunately, it crops the image and doesn't do so well with making a border for the image in the div as far as I've tried.

Answer (score 7):

Set the CSS class of your image container tag to `image-class`:

```
<div class="image-full"></div>
```

and add this you your CSS stylesheet.

```
.image-full {
    background: url(...some image...) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest for a responsive approach the best practice would be using the [Viewport units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) and min/max attributes as follows:

```
img{
  display: block;
  width: 12vw;
  height:12vw;
  max-width:100%;
  min-width:100px;
  min-height:100px;
  object-fit:contain;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To force image that fit in a exact size, you don't need to write too many codes. It's so simple

```css
img{
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: contain; /* Fit logo in the image size */
        -o-object-fit: contain; /* Fit logo fro opera browser */
    object-position: top; /* Set logo position */
        -o-object-position: top; /* Logo position for opera browser */
    }
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" alt="Logo">
```

Answer (score 6):

https://jsfiddle.net/sot2qgj6/3/

Here is the answer if you want to put image with **fixed percentage of width**, but **not fixed pixel of width**.

And this will be useful when dealing with **different size of screen**.

The tricks are

1. Using `padding-top` to set the height from width.
2. Using `position: absolute` to put image in the padding space.
3. Using `max-height and max-width` to make sure the image will not over the parent element.
4. using `display:block and margin: auto` to center the image.

I've also comment most of the tricks inside the fiddle.

---

I also find some other ways to make this happen.
There will be no real image in html, so I personly perfer the top answer when I need "img" element in html.

*simple css by using background*
***http://jsfiddle.net/4660s79h/2/***

*background-image with word on top*
***http://jsfiddle.net/4660s79h/1/***

the concept to use position absolute is from here
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp

Comment: This doesn't work if "height and width are already specified" as the original question mentions. There are times when you want to force width and height and then enlarge/shrink image according to the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
img { 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 600px; 
    object-fit: contain; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 50%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `aspect-ratio` property css

```
.my-image {
 aspect-ratio: 1/1; // square
 aspect-ratio: 16/9; // wide screen 1080p
 aspect-ratio: 4/3;
 aspect-ratio: 2/3;
}
```

Comment: The question is obviously when the aspect-ratio is unknown which is the majority of cases

Answer (score 3):

You can create a div like this:

```
<div class="image" style="background-image:url('/to/your/image')"></div>
```

And use this css to style it:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain; // this can also be cover
```

Comment: This will stretch the div to 100% width of it's parent, but not maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: Did you try it? I got it work https://jsfiddle.net/zuysj22w/. Can you show your case? @DavidBall

Comment: This is a similar solution to [Hoffmann's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16838011/247696).

Comment: it's ok if you don't want to get your images crawled. Otherwise you will need <img> for clear markup

Answer (score 3):

You can set the container to `display: flex` and `align-items: center` (other `align-items` values work too). Instead of `align-items` you can also set `align-self` on the image itself.

Answer (score 2):

This will make image shrink if it's too big for specified area (as downside, it will not enlarge image).

The solution by setec is fine for "Shrink to Fit" in auto mode. 
But, to optimally EXPAND to fit in 'auto' mode, you need to first put the received image into a temp id, 
Check if it can be expanded in height or in width (depending upon its aspect ration v/s the aspect ratio of your display block),

```
$(".temp_image").attr("src","str.jpg" ).load(function() { 
    // callback to get actual size of received image 

    // define to expand image in Height 
    if(($(".temp_image").height() / $(".temp_image").width()) > display_aspect_ratio ) {
        $(".image").css('height', max_height_of_box);
        $(".image").css('width',' auto');
    } else { 
        // define to expand image in Width
        $(".image").css('width' ,max_width_of_box);
        $(".image").css('height','auto');
    }
    //Finally put the image to Completely Fill the display area while maintaining aspect ratio.
    $(".image").attr("src","str.jpg");
});
```

This approach is useful when received images are smaller than display box. You must save them on your server in Original Small size rather than their expanded version to fill your Bigger display Box to save on size and bandwidth.

Comment: Although the question post didn't spell it out, I think OP strongly implied he/she was looking for a CSS-only solution.

Answer (score 2):

## You Can use:-

```
transform: scaleX(1.2);
```

to change the width without changing height.

**And**

```
transform: scaleY(1.2);
```

to change the height without changing width

*You can use this on images and video tags in html and css. This does not change the aspect ration also.*

Answer (score 1):

```css
img {
  max-width: 80px; /* Also works with percentage value like 100% */
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>This image is originally 400x400 pixels, but should get resized by the CSS:</p>
<img width="400" height="400" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEEkn.png">

<p>Let's say the author of the HTML deliberately wants
  the height to be half the value of the width,
  this CSS will ignore the HTML author's wishes, which may or may not be what you want:
</p>
<img width="400" height="200" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEEkn.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a pseudo element for vertical alignment? This less code is for a carousel but i guess it works on every fixed size container. It will keep the aspect ratio and insert @gray-dark bars on top/bottom or left/write for the shortest dimension. In the meanwhile the image is centered horizontally by the text-align and vertically by the pseudo element.

```
    > li {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: @gray-dark;
      text-align: center;

      > a img,
      > img {
        display: inline-block;
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
      }

      // Add pseudo element for vertical alignment of inline (img)
      &:before {
        content: "";
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Fullscreen presentation:

```
img[data-attribute] {height: 100vh;}
```

Keep in mind that if the view-port height is greater than the image the image will naturally degrade relative to the difference.