# how to make an image change when on different resolutions

Tags: html, css

I currently have a header which is of an image (the width = 1920px and height = 250) It sits at the very top of the page, and looks well with some resolutions.
But when i got to a resolution that actually changed my screen size, the image is still 1920px and then allows me to scroll. Is there a way of making it scale down to fit the page?

Comment: do you try set `width` of `image` is `100%`?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"

Answer (score 0):

You may use the responsive image code that is:-

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Else if you have images for multiple resolutions you are recommended to use media Queries:-

```css
//set width as per requirement

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  background-image: url(img/cover.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you showing the image in the header? Using `img` tag or using `background-image` CSS property?

- If you are using `<img>` tag, then you need to set `max-width: 100%;`
- If you are using `background-image` property, then you need to set `background-size: 100% auto;`

Hope this help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make your image responsive.

You can use bootstrap and add class for your image.

e.g

```
<img src="xyz.png" class="img-responsive">
```

OR

You can manually try to make your image responsive with CSS rules.

e.g

```
max-width:100% !important;
max-height:100% !important;
display:block;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have 2 things here.

1. As the screen size differs your image should get fit in the window.
2. You need to maintain the aspect ratio of the image in responsive design, otherwise your image will be stretched out (It is a challenge to maintain aspect ratio in responsive design).

For the first one you can use `width:100%` and `height:auto` also `max-width:100%` to make sure it does not cross your section.

If you are designing based on some particular resolution then use media query

```
@media (max-width:768px)
{
  width:... // define your width based on the resolution
}
```

Now the 2nd point : How to maintain aspect ratio. Follow the steps here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/maintain-image-aspect-ratios-responsive-web-design/

Also, found a stackoverflow post, which will be useful to you :[CSS force image resize and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio)