# Resize image without distorting it

Tags: css

Currently I am doing a very simple method of doing this with the code below.

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <img width="100%" height="250" src="http://i.imgur.com/lNB7QSt.jpg">
</div>
```

If I remove the `height="250"` portion of the code it prints the image to be the normal quality + normal size by I want it to be limited to 250 in height and return something like this image.

[image]

But instead it returns something which looks like the one displayed below.

[image]

Comment: I've read your question three times and still don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you only wish to maintain the aspect ratio, and not crop the image? And I am sort of with @j08691 on this one.. Still confused.

Comment: @Spyder_Says_hi yes that's what I want..

Comment: Isn't this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio

Comment: may be you can try max-height:250 and width:auto

Comment: *large putin meme*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the only sane approach I can think of (using `background-size: cover`). You can probably do something tricky with the existing markup but I don't feel like it'll leave you with anything flexible enough.

```css
.frame {
  height: 250px;
  background: transparent no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/lNB7QSt.jpg')"></div>
```

Answer (score 11):

What you should do is simply use 'auto' for the CSS width attribute like this:

```
<img style="width:auto; height:250px" src="http://i.imgur.com/lNB7QSt.jpg">
```

That should do what you're expecting.

Comment: They want it to crop to the center of the image. I assumed the same.

Comment: Nope, I don't think so... The question has an example of a scaled image. Not cropped. The OP doesn't seem to be very tech-savvy.

Comment: They were savvy enough to crop the image exactly how they'd like it displayed and it's also damn near precisely the center of the image.

Comment: and maybe `<img style="width:auto; height:100%; max-height:250px" src="http://i.imgur.com/lNB7QSt.jpg">` so in case the image is less than 250px high, it won't be expanded (= looking bad)

Answer (score 4):

I believe this can simply be done with object-fit.

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
 <img width="100%" height="250" src="http://i.imgur.com/lNB7QSt.jpg" style="object-fit: cover;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with setting width to 100%. Try removing width="100%", or set the width manually based on the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```css
img {
  display: block;

  max-height: 200px;
  width: max-content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the info from the link in the comment I made...

```css
img {
    display: block;
    max-width:230px;
    max-height:250px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <img width="100%" height="250" src="http://i.imgur.com/lNB7QSt.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image-name {

    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 250px;

}

.image-name2 {

    display: block;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 250px;

}
```

```html
<img class="image-name" width="100%" src="http://i.imgur.com/lNB7QSt.jpg?1">

Above is the image with no quality change + the width that you're looking for.


Below is the image with the height you're looking for but the width of the normal image.

<img class="image-name2" width="100%" src="http://i.imgur.com/lNB7QSt.jpg?1">
```