# Image height won't adjust when window re-sizes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like for an image to only display when the viewport size is less than 768px.

When less than 768px, the image should span the entire width of the window and should not distort (i.e. height should change proportionally with the width).

However, right now, I can't get the height to change when I resize the window.

I've tried changing the display to block and specifying `width:100%`, `height:auto`.

HTML:

```
<div class="row col-12" id="mobileimg">
    <img src="images/img.png" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mobileimg {
    display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

#mobileimg {
    display:flex;
    margin-top:20px;
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: check here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio

Comment: I tried that; scrollbars still appear after I set display to block, max-width to 768px, max-height to 200px, width:auto, and height:auto.

Comment: use (overflow: hidden;) to hide the scrollbars -- you can try the (object-fit) property -- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/  ---  but Microsoft are considering its use

Comment: Wouldn't overflow:hidden; only result in the image being cut off? I'd like the entire image to be shown. Object-fit doesn't seem to be working, either.

Comment: do a demo here -- https://jsfiddle.net/ -- and post the link in your Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the dimensions on the image itself. That makes the image responsive. Try this:

```css
#mobileimg {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #mobileimg {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row col-12" id="mobileimg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gLvvyLdf/)

Comment: This worked--thank you so much!--but I'm confused as to /why it works. Why do I have to specify width/height:100% separately under a different selector (i.e. why can't it just be a declaration under #mobileimg)?

Comment: `#mobileimg` selects the div (the images' container). `img` selects the image itself. If you apply the `width` / `height` to the div, that doesn't tell the image anything. So we target the image directly.