# Wordpress photo size issue on woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a e-commerce website using wordpress and woocommerce. The template that i'm using is Zerif-Lite. But i ran into a problem.

I've got a few products image in the woocomerce product page. However not all the image size are the same(some of them are 185x256 but some of them are 200 x 299). Therefore when the image shows up on the site would varies [example  photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wODI7.png) The idea that i'd like to fix it by putting the image inside the container [like this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMRe3.png) with the aspect ratio remaining.

I've tried to adjust the image size using the function provide by woo-commerce. But it doesn't change anything. I've try to google for the fix, and ran over some solution liking using thumbnail, but i wounder is there a way to achieve what I've mention above? or am i even heading the right directions?

Again many thanks for the Help :D

Comment: Not sure if it will help: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/manual-image-crop/ You can crop de image the way you want and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be to edit the printed div code or style for those images to have something like:

```
img {
display: block;
max-width:230px;
max-height:95px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

This will auto resize, but maintain dimensions. In your case, it seems height would need to be the limiting variable.

This seems like it may be a duplicate of this:  [CSS force image resize and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio)