# WordPress CSS - Get Images aligned

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In my website I have a row containing 3 images - http://icestartup.com/testsites/site248gfj/. You will be able to see it if you click on the main menu item called "ruimtes".

The 3 images are not having the same height. If i change my screen size the height keeps varying as well. I would like the 3 images to be of same height so that it looks aligned.

PS: I tried to use the CSS: height: 275px; but the image gets stretched! I don't like that. What i wanted was the image to be of same height without changing aspect ratio.

I am stuck with this CSS for an hour. Any idea folks?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `max-height: 242px;` This will work.!

Comment: That worked (Along with some help from Waxis comment above). Thanks brother.