# How to autofit image in container with constant aspect ratio using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

Source:

```
<div id="box">
   <div id="wrap">
      <img>
   </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#box {
   width: 500px;
   min-height: 400px;
   max-height: 600px;
}
```

How to autofit `img` with constant aspect ratio using only CSS? Here is an example of image properly fitting:

[image: example]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio

Comment: I don’t think that can be done using pure CSS, if you want the container to obey a min- and max-height as well.

Comment: explain your question, you can do images responsive and they the will resize  demo - https://jsfiddle.net/yc32n7ud/

Comment: @grinmax it's clear what the OP is asking. They need a solution beyond a simple responsive image. Depending on the aspect ratio they need an image to always fill the width and/or height of the container element if possible.

Comment: this can do only if image leave in background and add property background-size: cover;  https://jsfiddle.net/31h9vax6/

Answer (score 2):

```
#box {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

#box img {
width :100%;
}
```

try this to fix the image ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use `object-fit`.
It specifies how an image or video element should be resized to fit its container.

If you use `object-fit: cover;` it will cut off the sides of the image, preserving the aspect ratio, and also filling in the space:

```
#wrap img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

About the browser support:

[image]

More informations about this css property:
[object-fit CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Note:

> object-fit works for `<img>` and `<video>` elements only.

Comment: Based on the original question this is now the best answer. Just tested it out, works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was after... and I think what the OP wanted:

1. If image is tall fit height  (potentially letterboxing on left/right)
2. If image is wide fit width   (potentially letterboxing on top/bottom)

[image]

Here is the CSS...

```
.Image_Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.Image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
body {
  background: orange;
  margin:0;
}
```

Here is the HTML...

```
    <div class="Image_Container">
      <img class="Image" src="https://picsum.photos/400/800" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="Image_Container">
      <img class="Image" src="https://picsum.photos/800/301" />
    </div>
```

Here is the Code...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-9s6clh?file=styles.css

Disclaimer:

I am sure this can be simplified, hopefully not with some weird specs like -moz-moz, -webkit POLUTION, forget those none sense units like px,em,... viewport units all the way :)

I am no CSS guru, just hacking myself away into all this garbage languages/frameworks that fail to provide the **obvious** for the average human.

Answer (score -1):

Css for the parent container -  `min-height: 400px;   max-height: 600px;`

And then for the image itself:

```
#box {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

You could try this in your css

```
img {
     width:auto;
     height:auto;
    }
```

Or good old HTML

```
<img src="http://imageurl.jpg" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
```