# Prevent image from being out of focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to prevent the larger image from being out of focus, after clicking the thumbnail image?

```js
 'use strict';
  var my_image,
    my_imageSrc = 'https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1509a.jpg',//https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1509a.jpg
    y = document.getElementById('LargeImage');
  function PreloadImage(theElement) {
    my_image = new Image();
    my_image.onload = ShowLargeImage(my_imageSrc);
    my_image.src = my_imageSrc;
  }
  function ShowLargeImage(strImgSource) {
   if (my_image.complete) {
    y.src = strImgSource;
    y.style.display = 'block';
   }
  }
  function ShowThumbnail() {
   y.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

```css
div.gallery img{
 height: 70px;
 width: 140px;
} 
#LargeImage{ 
 display: none;
 height:100vh;
 left:0px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 width:100vw;
}
```

```html
 <div class="gallery"><img src="https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1509a.jpg"onclick="PreloadImage(this)"></div>
 <img src="" id="LargeImage" onclick="ShowThumbnail()">
```

Filler!   Filler!   Filler!

Comment: you have to keep aspect ratio

Comment: Instead of adding "Filler! Filler! Filler!" at the end of your post, could you please add a little more info regarding your question?

Comment: What is 'aspect ratio'? What more info is needed?

Comment: giving 100vw width and 100vh height, you are stretching the image. remove either width or height css and see difference. see this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio

Comment: The purpose is to fill the screen, and the image at the url is much bigger than the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```js
'use strict';
var my_image,
 my_imageSrc = 'https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1509a.jpg',//https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1509a.jpg
 y = document.getElementById('LargeImage');
function showImage(){
 var stats = document.getElementById('stats'),
  y = document.getElementById('LargeImage');
 stats.innerHTML = 'Ready, rendering...';
 while(!y.complete){
  setTimeout(function() {showImage()}, 10);
 }
 y.style.display = 'block';
 setTimeout(function() {stats.innerHTML = '';}, 3000);
 
}
function PreloadImage(theElement) {
 var my_image,
  my_imageSrc = 'https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1509a.jpg',
  stats = document.getElementById('stats'),
  y = document.getElementById('LargeImage');
 stats.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
 y.style.display = 'none';
 my_image = new Image();
 my_image.src = my_imageSrc;
 y.src = my_imageSrc+"?"+Date.now();
}
function ShowThumbnail() {
 var y = document.getElementById('LargeImage');
 y.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
div.gallery img{
 /*height: 70px;*/ /* EDIT - commented to keep aspect ratio */
 width: 140px;
} 
#LargeImage{ 
 display: none;
 /*height:100vh;*/ /* EDIT - commented to keep aspect ratio */
 left:0px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 width:100vw;
}
```

```html
 <div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1509a.jpg" onclick="PreloadImage(this)">
 </div>
 <span id="stats"></span>
 <img src="" id="LargeImage" onclick="ShowThumbnail()" onload="showImage()">
```

Once your image have a width higher than height you need to set only the new width and let the browser do the trick with the new height

**EDIT**

and if you don't want scroll bars when the large image comes up, add to your css(consider the snippet scope):

```
/* this will avoid the scroll bar */
body{overflow:hidden}
```

**EDIT 2**

if the width of the image needs to fit the screen/page:

```js
'use strict';
var my_image,
 my_imageSrc = 'https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1509a.jpg',//https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1509a.jpg
 y = document.getElementById('LargeImage');
function showImage(){
 var stats = document.getElementById('stats'),
  y = document.getElementById('LargeImage');
 stats.innerHTML = 'Ready, rendering...';
 while(!y.complete){
  setTimeout(function() {showImage()}, 10);
 }
 y.style.display = 'block';
 setTimeout(function() {stats.innerHTML = '';}, 3000);
 
}
function PreloadImage(theElement) {
 var my_image,
  my_imageSrc = 'https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1509a.jpg',
  stats = document.getElementById('stats'),
  y = document.getElementById('LargeImage');
 stats.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
 y.style.display = 'none';
 my_image = new Image();
 my_image.src = my_imageSrc;
 y.src = my_imageSrc+"?"+Date.now();
}
function ShowThumbnail() {
 var y = document.getElementById('LargeImage');
 y.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
div.gallery img{
 /*height: 70px;*/ /* EDIT - commented to keep aspect ratio */
 width: 140px;
} 
#LargeImage{ 
 display: none;
 /*height:100vh;*/ /* EDIT - commented to keep aspect ratio */
 left:0px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1509a.jpg" onclick="PreloadImage(this)">
 </div>
 <span id="stats"></span>
 <img src="" id="LargeImage" onclick="ShowThumbnail()" onload="showImage()">
```

Comment: The image is still out of focus.

Comment: @Zuffa, just the small and I've just updated my answer to it keeps their aspect ratio. Please, take a look at the code snippet

Comment: The larger image is out of focus for about 1 second, after clicking the thumbnail, that is the thing I would like to prevent.

Comment: @Zuffa, I've updated my answer, please check the code snippet again