# Bootstrap Vertical align in Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a jumbotron with one row and two columns for Desktop view. The row height depends on the text. I want to center an image vertically to the text beside.

I'm using a grid layout with two columns for this and following code to vertically center the image:

```css
#jumbotron-introduction {
    
    background-color: white;
}

#p-introduction {
    
    font-size: 16px;
}

#image-introduction {
    
    width: 100%;
}

.vcenter {
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-introduction">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <h3>...</h3>
                    
                    <p id="p-introduction">...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 vcenter">
                    <img src="Images/..." id="image-introduction">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But nothing changes, the image is still centered on the top of the column. I also tried the following code:

```css
.vcenter {
    
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But it's the same result, nothing happens.

Thats how it looks like at the moment
[image]

But I want it to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When ever I need to center something in HTML - the [css-tricks guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) is always help me to do so.
I suggest you read and save it for next time you need to center something!

For your question, you can achieve the desired result using flexbox -
Set the .vcenter display to flex, so you can use the `align-items` property.

```css
.jumbotron__container {
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
}

.jumbotron__text {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.jumbotron__image {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-introduction">
        <div class="jumbotron__container">
          <div class="jumbotron__text">
            <h3>Loren And Ipsum</h3>
            <p id="p-introduction">Dolum And Smith<p>
          </div>
          <div class="jumbotron__image">
            <img src="Images/..." id="image-introduction">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not working for me, the image is still centered on the top

Comment: Can you please try now? I edited my answer.
If it still not works for you, please share the full code.

Comment: it's still not working, I added the full code for this

Comment: Can you describe more what is your desired result?

 the image and the paragraph should be in the same line inside the jumbotron?

Comment: I added some drawings to my question

Comment: Vishnus solution is working with a fixed row height for me but I have no fixed height

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it will work for you, but let me know anyway.
I recommended about learning flexbox before other CSS frameworks as bootstrap - you might not need them.

[MDN For flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Comment: When I try it just with the code from you it's working as expected. But if I use my Image, the Image is displayed in original size so it is much greater than the text

Comment: Well, thats another topic - image resize and aspect ratio. I guess [this](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=css+keep+image+aspect+ratio+responsive&oq=css+keep+image+aspect+ratio+responsive&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.5768j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) could help you.

Comment: Thanks, its now working with your code togheter with help of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio

Comment: Sure! glad it helped. Good luck mate

Answer (score 2):

I think it was still in beta when the question was asked, but Bootstrap 4 has new [flexbox-based utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/) that make this easy. In particular, `align-self-center` would have done what you were looking for:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron bg-light">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <h3>Text</h3>
                <p class="h4">Text</p>
                <p>Text</p>
                <p>More text</p>
                <p>Even more text</p>
                <p>Just a little more text</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 align-self-center">
                <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/avatar_square_grey_48dp.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Snippet doesn't seem to work unless it's full screen BTW.)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#image-introduction{
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 45%;
}
.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-6 {
    display: table-cell;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="parent">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
             <img src="..." id="image-introduction">            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `inline-block` helper.

```css
.vcenter {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
  height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#image-introduction {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.inline-block-helper {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 vcenter">
  <span class="inline-block-helper"></span>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" id="image-introduction">
</div>
```