# center a div within a column nested under a flex row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I'm trying to center (horizontally and vertically) a div inside a column (it's the one with `class="centered-column"`) nested under a flex row.

I tried to apply the inforamtion given on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479402), and also on [this css-tricks guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/), without success.

Here's the code:

```css
span {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.row {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}
.col-md-8 {
 background-color: lightblue;
}
.centered-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <span>Row number 1</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <span>Row number 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
       <div class="centered-column">
          <span>Some text<span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What should I do to make it work (Note that I have to use Bootstrap 3)?

Comment: you are almost, make the center class a little upper, on its parent container `col-md-8` ... as a side note: better upgrade to V4 of bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the `.centered-column` height. Otherwise, it has the height of its children. The children are vertically centered, but not in the column:

```css
span {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.row {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}
.col-md-8 {
 background-color: lightblue;
}
.centered-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <span>Row number 1</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <span>Row number 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
       <div class="centered-column">
          <span>Some text<span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or we put the center class with the col-md-8 and we remove an extra div ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif agreed. But in doing so we only help OP. In explaining the principle, we teach all future visitors and OP how this works. What's the goal here?

Comment: yes I know, we should teach everyone, but my comment was another alternative ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, applying `flex` on the column instead of the child works. That's the problem with flexbox: you need to apply it to all chain of parents from the one setting height to the one that should expand, in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

As @Temani afif commented, the only change that's needed is:

```
<div class="col-md-8 centered-column">
   <span>Some text<span>
</div>
```

full snippet:

```css
span {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.row {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}
.col-md-8 {
 background-color: lightblue;
}
.centered-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <span>Row number 1</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <span>Row number 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 centered-column">
       <span>Some text<span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would also remove the useless div and keep only the span ;)