# Image beyond div - Needing of max 150px height, to fit and keep it's aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

How to get image to fit in div (don't go beyond it) and keep it's aspect ratio while never having more than `150px` in `height`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

 <div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 200px; width: 200px;">
  <img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/02/congratulations_-banner.png" style="max-height: 150px; width: auto;" />
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see here image `width` is `auto` and `max-height` is `150px` although this image goes beyond parent div and his borders.

How to make this image keep it's aspect ratio and fit in this div and scale down but also having `max-height` of `150px`. So never height is more than `150px` and `width` is `auto` to this `height` to keep it's ascpet ratio and also fit in this div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17183996/6838730)

you can use

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 200px; width: 200px;">
    <img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/02/congratulations_-banner.png" style="max-width: 100%;  max-height: 100%;" />
</div>
```

note:

It would be better to separate CSS from HTML as [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/271338/280204) explains. So instead you should use the code below

```css
#bannerContainer
{
  border: 1px solid black; 
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px;
}
#banner {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bannerContainer">
  <img id="banner" src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/02/congratulations_-banner.png"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the `img`  `max-width:100%`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

 <div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 200px; width: 200px;">
  <img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/02/congratulations_-banner.png" style="max-height: 150px; max-width:100%; width: auto;" />
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```