# Change image height without stretching the image

Tags: css

The image is stretched when I try to make the size smaller.

http://jsfiddle.net/QEpJH/878/

```
.container img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    /*object-fit: cover; // doesn't work in Internet Explorer */
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS force image resize and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 4):

You need to make it scalable by `1:1`

so use
`width: auto;` instead of `width:100;`.

or use `height: auto;` and `width: 100%;` in case you want to cover the whole width.

*But remember if you cover the whole width, the height will increase*.

Comment: I need the image to have a full width, but the height to be smaller, like 60 of the view port.

Comment: Try using background-image and use background-size: contain or cover. Otherwise use a container wrapping your image with an height of 60vh and overflow hidden. But you should use a horizontal taken imageinstead of an vertical taken. It makes it easer for you :)

Here is an other example. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Rakowu/QEpJH/880/

Comment: *EDIT: Here is an other example. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Rakowu/QEpJH/881/

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `width` to `auto`, the image will adjust itself to the given height without any stretch.

```
.container img {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        height: 60vh;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ratio in only percentage or use similar ratio

```
.container img {
   display: block;
   width: 30%;
   height: 30%;
   /*object-fit: cover; // doesn't work in Internet Explorer */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set the image as a background instead and use

```
background-size:cover
```

you will lose the stretching but some of the image may get cut off

to counter this slightly you can use

```
background-position
```

to position the image in a more desirable place