# Make the image fit with div without losing any content in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a div wrapping two images. I want the second image to fit within the div because the width and height are dynamic.

My code looks like this:

```css
.box {
  width: 640px;
  height: 540px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-border {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="target">
  <div align="center">
    <img src="http://cdn.tgdd.vn/Files/2014/06/24/551004/game-duoi-hinh-bat-chu4.jpg" width="60%" height="60%">
  </div>
  <img class="img-border" id="imgQues" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-K5SwATiq6cI/U84bk7MZPWI/AAAAAAAADkI/4lWV0ErVAFs/s1600/2014-07-22+14.11.00-1.png" />
  <div class="comment" id="chatbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem you can see at `.img-border` is not fitting (stretch and resize) into `.box` div and keeping its aspect ratio.

Is there any method to fit the second image `img-border` in div and keep ratio?

Comment: Take a look at [CSS force image resize and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12991351/215552) and see if it helps.

Comment: Use background-image instead with background-size:cover;

Comment: @KunalKhatri the image should be source because it's variable, values change every time.

Comment: You can set background-image dynamically using jquery as per requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```css
.box {
  width: 640px;
  height: 540px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  /**
    Just for visualization 
  **/
  background: gray;
}

/**
  Just dummy names, rename as you like
*/
.box__first-child,
.box__second-child {
  float: left;
  width: 49.99999999%;
}

/**
  Force images to always take remaining space
*/
.box img {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-border {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="target">
  <div class="box__first-child" align="center">
    <img src="http://cdn.tgdd.vn/Files/2014/06/24/551004/game-duoi-hinh-bat-chu4.jpg" width="60%" height="60%">
  </div>
  <div class="box__second-child">
    <img class="img-border" id="imgQues" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-K5SwATiq6cI/U84bk7MZPWI/AAAAAAAADkI/4lWV0ErVAFs/s1600/2014-07-22+14.11.00-1.png" />
    <div class="comment" id="chatbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The html changes are not mandatory, you can do it in another way too, but this seems to be the cleanest for me. The trick basically is to force the images to always take up full space and align the items after each other with float.

**Edit:**

[image: Preview Variant 1]

[jsfiddle - variant 1](https://jsfiddle.net/4otkauqj/)

[image: Preview Variant 2]

[jsfiddle - variant 2](https://jsfiddle.net/n7btvdoc/)

Comment: It should be two different row. Your example, two images in the same line. I want to first image should have 1/3 at top of div, the second image should be 2/3 on the bottom.

Comment: @vanloc I added both variants i think you could mean ... sry i am not so good at this :D