# Images in flex layout not keeping aspect ratio on chrome

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, cross-browser, angular-flex-layout

So I am trying to create two rows of 5 images. I did the following :

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <!-- Some text -->
  </div>
  <div class="secondary-header">
    <!-- Some more text -->
  </div>
  <div class="top-margin" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center top">
    <img *ngFor="let i of images" [src]="i" fxFlex="20">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container {
  padding: 2.5% 5%;
}

.header {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: "Yanone Kaffeesatz";
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}

.secondary-header {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Yanone Kaffeesatz";
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}

.top-margin {
  margin-top: 2.5%;
}
```

This solution turns out perfect on Firefox 64:

[image: Perfect results on Firefox 64]

However, the images have a greater height on Chrome 71, breaking the aspect ratio:

[image: Not working on Chrome 71]

None of the solutions found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio) worked. I am using Angular 7.1.4 and Flex Layout 7.0.0-beta.22.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
img {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

Could you provide a link to an example?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and eventually found a nicer solution. You have to add this to your img tag:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

Here is a full discussion: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/225