# How do I mantain original image ratio?

Tags: html, css

How do I mantain original image ratio?

If I have a "img" element and I do "style="width: 25px; height: auto;"" the image doesn't have automatic height, it is modified. How do I get auto height?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Do you mean you want to maintain the height? Regardless of the width? Your question is unclear as it stands.

Comment: an image will by default keep its ratio is specify either the height or the width and not both at the same time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS force image resize and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

The `width` and `height` properties of `img` tags do this by default.

```html
<img width="100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562939230-e05e7c80c1d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=652&q=80" />
<hr />
<img width="25" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562939230-e05e7c80c1d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=652&q=80" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code given below.

```css
#one {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto:
}

#two {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto:
}
```

```html
<img id="one" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/120/180" />

<img id="two" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/120/180" />
```