# How to resize an image so it is always the biggest possible without the being bigger than the window height OR than the window width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image I want as big as possible, but I want 100% of the image visible no matter how the window is resized.  I also want to maintain image ratio.

I have tried doing

```
img{
   width: 100vh;
}
```

but that will cut off some of the image depending on the size of the window.

Here are some examples of what I want:

[When the width is restrictive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb1aV.png)

[When the height is restrictive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1fRb.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS force image resize and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio)

Comment: for "as big as possible", perhaps you're looking for `100vmin`?

Comment: `width: 100vw; height: 100vmin;` did keep it max size, except it then doesn't maintain aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set your image with screen size then use object-fit: cover to set image always fitting the container;

```
img{
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: They want `contain`, not `cover` cc @JoeyCarlisle

Comment: @Kaiido, That worked! thank you.  I'll choose your answer if you decide to write it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it will max out the width of the containing element and also use height auto to maintain the aspect ratio of the image(s)

```
img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
  }
```

Comment: This behaves the same as original code, I have to scroll to see the whole image, which is undesired.