# Keep Image Ascpect Ratio

Tags: image, grid-layout, aspect-ratio

I'm currently refactoring my website and try to get rid of a few breakpoints. 
In my portfolio, I have an image gallery, which displays 3x3 image tiles. Those tiles are built with css grid. The tiles in my example should be 200px high and minmax (200px, 333px) width.

Currently, the tiles work as expected. But the images don't keep their aspect ratio. Is there any way to keep the original ratio and cut the images in their height? The smallest version of the container should be 200x200.

https://codepen.io/yanniksturm/pen/LYVegro

```
<div class="content">

  <div id="img1" class="imageWrapper">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562886889-4ff7af0602ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2089&q=80">
  </div>
  <div id="img2" class="imageWrapper">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562886889-4ff7af0602ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2089&q=80">
  </div>
  <div id="img3" class="imageWrapper">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562886889-4ff7af0602ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2089&q=80">
  </div>

</div>

.content {
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 999px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
    backgeound-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax (200px, 333px) minmax (200px, 333px) minmax (200px, 333px);
  grid-template-rows: 200px;

}

.imageWrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

}

img {
   height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

}

#img1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}
#img2 {
 grid-column: 2;
}

#img3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS force image resize and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio)

Comment: @Roy unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `img` width and height to `auto` and add a `max-width: 100%;` to it in order to keep the aspect ratio.

```css
img {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

See below snippet.

You could use `object-fit: cover;` but that is [not supported in older browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit) (I am looking at IE11).

```css
.content {
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 999px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  backgeound-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax (200px, 333px) minmax (200px, 333px) minmax (200px, 333px);
  grid-template-rows: 200px;
}

.imageWrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#img1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

#img2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

#img3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div id="img1" class="imageWrapper">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562886889-4ff7af0602ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2089&q=80">
  </div>
  <div id="img2" class="imageWrapper">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562886889-4ff7af0602ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2089&q=80">
  </div>
  <div id="img3" class="imageWrapper">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562886889-4ff7af0602ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2089&q=80">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Fortunately, I don't have to support IE11  `object-fit: cover;` will work for me. Thanks!