# React Native: Image "contain" is behaving the same as "cover"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-image

I have the following image that I want to sit as a header in my React Native app:

[image]

I want all the text in my `<ScrollView>` to flow behind that header. I've been able to do this with the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}>
          <View
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              width: "100%",
              top: 0
            }}
          >
            <ImageBackground
              source={require('../../images/swoord-top.png')}
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                resizeMode: "contain",
                justifyContent: 'center'
              }}
            >
              <View style={{
                backgroundColor: 'green',
                height: 500,
                width: 25
              }}></View>
            </ImageBackground>
          </View>
        <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'pink', zIndex: -1}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 42}}>
          Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor
        </Text>
      </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This looks like this:

[image]

The green bar on the lefthand side defines the height of the header. The problem is that the `<BackgroundImage>` stretches to fit the header container vertically, and spills out the sides, even though I've specified `resizeMode: cover`.

**What I Want To Know:**

How do I make the background image compress to fit in the screen horizontally?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<ImageBackground />`  does not work as `<Image />` so `resizeMode` contain will not work, you can either give fixed height and width to the parent view of `<ImageBackgroud/>` or you can use `<Image />` with position absolute to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Ramashish, thank you, that does answer my question. I posted one more here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60946102/react-native-why-is-image-stretching-vertically-to-fill-container-and-how-to-pr) if you have any insight on that I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @gkeenley sure I would love to help but ,

Answer (score 1):

In  instead of giving resizemode inside style use it as:-

```
<ImageBackground resizeMode={"contain"} />
```

Image and ImagebackGround have different properties.

Comment: Hi Bhavya, thank you, this helped me resolve it. I had to give the approval to ramashish because he got to it first, but I appreciate your help and upvoted. I posted one more here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60946102/react-native-why-is-image-stretching-vertically-to-fill-container-and-how-to-pr) if you have any insight on that I'd appreciate it.