# how to fit large image in small div

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image of `1920*1300` ratio which I want to be displayed in which ever device the website is running and I want the image to cover whole div.

Here's my code:

```css
.carousel {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Image does not render proper*/
  object-fit: cover;
  /* Image gets streched */
  object-fit: fill;
  /* Does not fill the whole carousel */
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section class="carousel">
  <a href="\calculator">
    <img class="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1930x1300" /></a>
</section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS force image resize and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

> Make sure you set both `aspect-ratios` of the `container` *and* the `image` to the same number

---

It will **never(*)** be a `100%` perfect match, because of the `aspect-ratio`. You can set either of the sides to match `100%` and the other can be `auto` which will be relative to the other (maintaining the `aspect-ratio`) so it will scale without distortion with the parent container.

If you set both to exactly `100%` then one part (either `width` or `height`) will be smaller than the `container`. If you don't care about the `aspect-ratio` you can stretch it.

---

**(*)** It will only work like you intended `iff` the `container` has the same `aspect-ratio` as your `image`.

In your case, the window is `100vw / 80vh` which results in a `5/4` ratio (`1.25`). The image however is:
`~ 31/21` (`~ 1.4769`).

Therefore, if you apply the `container-ratio` to your image: `1920 x (1300 * 1.1815)` you get `1920 x 1536 => 1920 / 1536 = 1.25`. Now if you do:

```css
.carousel a {
  display: block;
}

.carousel img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

It should exactly fit while maintaining the `aspect-ratio`. Even when the image is bigger or smaller in size (e.g. `480 x 384, 960 x 768, 1920 x 1300` etc.). But this is a special case (see 2nd snippet).

If all your images are in this `1920 x 1300` format for example, then you could just adjust the `height` of the `container` instead (which is the other way around so to say).

```css
.carousel {
  width: 100vw;
  /* 100 / (1920 / 1300) */
  height: 67.70vh
}
```

**First, general example (container-aspect-raito: 5/4, image-aspect-ratio: ~31/21)**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel a {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.carousel img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="carousel">
  <a href="\calculator">
    <img class="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1300" /></a>
</section>
```

**Second, specific example (container-aspect-ratio: 5/4, image-aspect-ratio: 5/4)**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel {
  /* same ratio as 5/4 i.e. 100%/80% */
  width: 480px;
  /* ... */
  height: 384px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel a {
  display: block;
}

.carousel img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="carousel">
  <!-- I made the image smaller so that it is better to see in the snippet but you could also use 1920x1300 ofc. -->
  <a href="\calculator"><img class="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/960x768" /></a>
</section>
```

Comment: A really nice and espacially complete anwser to the issue. I rarely see anwsers that are complete and not just a partial solution. Really like it!

Answer (score 0):

image to fit the `width` of parent div

```css
img {
 width: 100%
 height:auto
}
```

image to fit the `height` of parent div

```css
img {
 width: auto
 height: 100%
}
```

image to fit `height` and `width` of parent div

```css
img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```