# Image height and aspect ratio for equal columns

Tags: html, css

I have three images next one the other creating a 3 column layout of images.
I need this images to have a specific height so they're cropped to this height no matter how the image is.

The point is that I need those images to keep an aspect ratio depending on how you resize your window.

If I declare an specific height (i.e. 700px or 70vh), the aspect is so much different if, let's say, the window is 1900px wide or 700px.

Is there a way I can "lock" the height dimensions of the images so they keep their aspect no matter how's your screen and considering every image might not have same height as the other?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if the images don't have te same ratio, you will have to stretch some of them. which diesn't look nice. you can manually edit images so they have the same ratio, afterwards you can set a fixed height

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code

Comment: it would be great if you show your HTML and CSS codes.

Comment: you probably look for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position to set which sides / how to crop them.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this,

- use **background images** instead of putting the image into the div - this is very flexible.
- **object-fit** works on the image itself but you have to set the dimensions on the image, not just the container. There is more support now for this than there was but as usual IE is a problem.

For both of these you want to use `cover` so that the image is made big enough to fill the container but will crop off the parts that don't fit.

The code to do both of these ways is next. See the comments for how it works:

**Background Images**

```css
.column {
  /* this is the important bit */
  background-size: cover;
  /* this is where the image is positioned. 
  This puts it horizontally centered and vertically at the top 
  You can use left, right, bottom or values in px or %  */
  background-position: center top;
  
  /* this is not important. It is to make columns so you can see it work*/
  width: 30%;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;

}

/* put the images as background images.*/
.pic1 { background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/300x700"); }
.pic2 { background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/250x400"); }
.pic3 { background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"); }
```

```html
<div class="column pic1"></div>
<div class="column pic2"></div>
<div class="column pic3"></div>
```

**Object Fit**

```css
/* this is the important bit */
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  /* you must set the sizes here or it won't work. e.g. */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* this is not important. It is to make columns so you can see it work */
.column {
  width: 30%;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="column"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x700"></div>
<div class="column"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x400"></div>
<div class="column"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"></div>
```

**Another example with real photos so you can see that they keep their aspect ratio and do not stretch when you resize the window.** The real image size is the dimensions in the url:

- image 1 is 300px * 700px
- image 2 is 250px * 400px
- image 3 is 300px * 300px

```css
/* this is the important bit */
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  /* you must set the sizes here or it won't work. e.g. */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* this is not important. It is to make columns so you can see it work */
.column {
  width: 30%;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="column"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/MJBh9NBoD20/300x700"></div>
<div class="column"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/afuOsuzyx24/250x400"></div>
<div class="column"><img src="h
ttps://source.unsplash.com/dOmKEVCg94s/300x300"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem comes with the resize of the window. There are 3 images of 33.33% of width creating three columns. If I set a fixed height (ie. 700px) the visual aspect is different when resizing.

Comment: @Anta The examples in my answer work. The height is fixed and when the width resizes the images don't change aspect ratio. Run the code snippet and click "Full page" and you will see the images have the same aspect ratio and are not stretched. If you didn't know, the words written in the images are the actual size of the image.

Comment: @Anta I have edited my answer to show you another example with real photos so you can see better that this is working.

Comment: @Anta Can you see this is working now? If it is helpful maybe you can accept it? Upvoting all the good answers is nice too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set min/max width and height atributtes:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width:230px;
  max-height:95px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>This image is originally 400x400 pixels, but should get resized by the CSS:</p>
<img width="400" height="400" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEEkn.png">
```

Or you can use `object-fit: cover;` CSS property. Notice that this will preserve the ratio, but may "crop" the image. For more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio). It will be more specific.

Comment: the op seems okay to crop img, there is 3 of them on a single row ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the images to a percentage of it's parent container. For example:

```
body {
   height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
}

img {
   width: 50%;
}
```

This will ensure that the images will always occupy 50 percent of the container that it's in, which in this case is the body.

Comment: 3 images are supposed to be on a row ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

```css
.container{
  width: 300px; /* arbitrary width, use yours */
}

.container > div{
  width: 33.3%; /* 1/3 = 33.3 For 3 elements for each row */
  height: 100px; /* arbitrary height, use yours */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px; /* space between images */
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden; /* crop image if they are not an exact square */
}
.container > div > img{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div><img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300' alt='first sample image'/></div>
  <div><img src='https://picsum.photos/300/400' alt='second sample image'/></div>
  <div><img src='https://picsum.photos/400/400' alt='third sample image'/></div>
</div>
```

You can use `background-image` too, but then the source of your images should be declare in CSS. Prefer [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) when you have multiple images, like in a gallery.

Comment: flex can make the code shorter ;) https://jsfiddle.net/t65xwszr/