# How do I make sure that the images aren't stretching either horizontally or vertically

Tags: css, reactjs

They should only be resized on one of the two dimensions, whichever is bigger.

If you look at the puppy image below, it looks to be stetched
[image]

CODE

```
export const ImageTemplateImage = styled.img`
  width: 230px;
  height: 162.53px; 
`;
```

Comment: I think this will answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 1):

If you don't give in a height for example, it will keep the ratio and only change the width.
Therefore the height may not be set.
At least is in css, I'm not familiar with reactjs, but I'm guessing this is an injection into the css.

Comment: yea its kinda like an inject into the css, im thinking of just removing the height since that is the main issue for making it stretched