# Technique to fit images several images within a max width/height in a grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, layout

I have been staring at this for about an hour, trying every permutation [How to force image resize and keep aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/how-to-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio) but none of it solves my case.

Here are two images which I've manually resized here so you can see them both at once:

**highly vertical image**

[image]

**very much horizontal image**

[image]

In theory, the vertical image can be 10,000+px tall, meanwhile the horizontal one can get to about 4,000px wide, or we can have 1 10000px tall image, and one 100px wide image, so the sizes can vary a great deal.

I would like to lay these out in a grid basically, where each image gets at most a square, and if it is tall, it can be squeezed/packed together on the x-axis. I think I want to lay them out something like this:

[image]

So it's about a square 250x250px on all sides where an image can possibly go. If it's too tall, shrink the image down and it gets put in a thinner horizontal space but fills the height. If it's too short but too wide, it only grows to 250px. Otherwise the images are bottom aligned to the grid. They are in no particular order.

In my case, I am taking an `ArrayBuffer` or `File` object and converting it to the image, through the dataURI system, so I *think* I can get access to the actual width/height of the image and use that in any calculations that might be necessary. I am 80% sure this can't be done in pure CSS (after that link above), so what sort of trick or simple algorithm could I use to lay the images out like this? Do I need to use JavaScript to make it happen? I have been at the general problem for a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `max-width` and `max-height` properties to limit the dimensions and place the images in a `<p>` element to have them bottom-aligned:

```css
img {
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/250">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/500">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/500/50">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/250/50">
</p>
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Wow, easy as that, I tried everything...