# Create an image cloud

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create an image cloud where images are stacked with each other and resize according to the number of times the image has been seen.

The cloud probably takes a predefined space too. Is it possible with javascript or do I need to go for SVG/Canvas??

Something similar to this: [hitlantis](http://hitlantis.com/)

Any pointers / references would be nice.

Comment: First, the example is in Flash. Second, [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: yes. the example is in flash. and i dont want code. i am only looking for pointers. to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things for you to look at:

- [javascript Image Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170624/javascript-image-resize) - You may need to move the element to make it look right, but this can probably be done in CSS
- [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)
- jQuery [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)
- [css :hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:hover)

Javascript may not even be necessary, provided you use `:hover` appropriately with the correct transitions/styling.

**Edit:**

For layering, use `z-index`. I'm not sure how you want to position your elements, so come up with an algorithm for placing them (random would probably work fine). Once that's done, just use `position: absolute`, setting `top` and `right` to the positions you generated.

Possible algorithms for placement:

- Random (easy peasy: `x = Math.random() * maxWidth - radius + centerX`), similar for y
- [Fibonacci-based using Vogel's model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#In_nature)- Ensures easy distribution
- Cluster similar images- this is a bit more difficult and depends on your clustering logic

I'm sure there are others. I'd recommend doing a simple one (random), getting everything working, then create a more interesting algorithm later if you want to.

Comment: what i am most concerned with is how I'd stack those images and how those images will take up space where they take up space

Comment: Updated my answer. I'd recommend just randomly distributing our images. That will give you a pretty good effect for the least amount of effort.