# Validate image filetype/filesize, crop, resize & then upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, client

I'm looking for a client side solution to validate whether the image being uploaded is of accepted file type, file size & then  crop the image as directed by user, re-size it to fit within some particular dimensions & then upload the re-sized & optimized image to server.

Are there any well known open-source libraries that can help me implement this ? (Multiple files uploading not needed). I'm not wanting to implement this myself & looking for a library that can provide a cross browser compatible solution with fallbacks for old/unsupported browsers.

I came across plupload & agile uploader, but those don't help in cropping images as per user directions.

---

Using jQuery 1.7. Open to add other libraries too in case required.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://wolframhempel.com/2012/12/02/photobooth-js/). It should help you with the cropping/resizing.

Comment: Since uploaders come aplenty and your pain really is cross browser cropping/resizing. You can try this [plugin](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/). I have used this in the past on a small project and worked fine for me.
Goes without saying that you can test the demo across browsers.

Comment: Just remember that you **MUST** **ReValidate** input in the server side. **NEVER, ever, ever, trust user input**.

Answer (score 4):

peace be upon you brother

i'm using what you want in my project but no ( resize photo as i put custom size for images )

i using ( imgareaselect ) to crop photo

but i don't remember the site of it, maybe: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/examples.html

if is it that site right, i'm using this code

```
   var x1 = null, y1 = null, w = null, h = null, Signal = null, object=null;

   function preview(img, selection) {
    var img = {
        url: jQuery("#image").attr("src"),
        width: jQuery("#image").width(),
        height: jQuery("#image").height()
    }

    var scaleX = 128 / selection.width;  // 128 = my custom size ;)
    var scaleY = 128 / selection.height; 
    $(".avatar-box img").replaceWith('<img id="thumbnail" src="'+img.url+'" class="preview" border="0"/>');


    $('#thumbnail').css({ 
      width: Math.round(scaleX * img.width) + 'px', 
      height: Math.round(scaleY * img.height) + 'px',
      marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px', 
      marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px' 
    });

    x1 = selection.x1; y1 = selection.y1; w = selection.width; h = selection.height;
   }
$(window).ready(function () {
 $('#image').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '1:1', onSelectChange: preview });
});
```

and to check the size and type: i use also this script

```
   $("form").submit(function(){
     var OrgFile = $(this).find("[type=file]"),
         FileName = OrgFile.val(),
         FileExtension = FileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
         if(FileName.indexOf(".")==-1 || FileExtension != "jpg" && FileExtension != "jpeg" && FileExtension != "png" && FileExtension != "gif" ){ // Curstom File Extension
          alert("This isn't a Photo !");
          return false;
         }else
         if((OrgFile[0].files[0].size/1024/1024) > (1)){ // Max Photo Size 1MB
          alert("You Photo is too big !");
          return false;
         }else{
          alert("every thing Fine :)");
          return true;
         }
   });
```

Then if the client submit the cropped image

```
  $('#create_thumbnail').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
     type : "POST",
     url : "resize.php",
     data : {logged_code: logged_code,x1: x1,y1: y1,w: w,h: h},
     success: function(data) {}
    });
    return false;
  });
```

And resize.php file

```
    function resizeThumbnailImage($thumb_image_name, $image, $width, $height, $start_width, $start_height, $scale){
        list($imagewidth, $imageheight, $imageType) = getimagesize($image);
        $imageType = image_type_to_mime_type($imageType);
        $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
        $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
        $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
        switch($imageType) {
            case "image/gif":
                $source=imagecreatefromgif($image); 
                break;
            case "image/pjpeg":
            case "image/jpeg":
            case "image/jpg":
                $source=imagecreatefromjpeg($image); 
                break;
           case "image/png":
            case "image/x-png":
                imagealphablending($newImage, false);
                imagesavealpha($newImage, true);  
                $source=imagecreatefrompng($image); 
                break;
        }
        imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,$start_width,$start_height,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);
        switch($imageType) {
            case "image/gif":
                imagegif($newImage,$thumb_image_name); 
                break;
            case "image/pjpeg":
            case "image/jpeg":
            case "image/jpg":
                imagejpeg($newImage,$thumb_image_name,100); 
                break;
            case "image/png":
            case "image/x-png":
                imagepng($newImage,$thumb_image_name);  
                break;
      }
        chmod($thumb_image_name, 0777);
        return $thumb_image_name;
    }
```

i hope that i help you and understand your question,

please vopte my answer that i want to join php chat room to find one help me in a problem

sorry for my bad english i'm speaking arabic

Answer (score 1):

Resizing can be done with FileReader and a canvas.
Create a canvas with wanted size.

Load the image. Then use the canvas.toDataURL(fileType) to get the file content as base64

Comment: not wanting to implement myself as it would be a great hassle to build a cross browser compatible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/#features) for the client side validation and uploading; with [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) for the cropping of the image afterwards.

Fine uploader is excellent for restricting the size and file type ([See here](http://fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-demo.html#demo3)) on the client side; however it does depend on which browsers you need to support (I believe IE7 won't allow you to validate on the client side like this).

Whilst JCrop is an easy to implement cropping tool which supports aspect ratios and converting images between their display and actual sizes.

Answer (score 1):

There are several separate things here:

- Validating image/file type. This can be done at the client side, but you will need to do it at the server again for security. For a file input that only accepts images, you can use:

  ```
  <input type="file" accept='image/*'>
  ```
- Letting the user crop the image. There are several libraries here, the most prominent one being Jcrop. But there are alternatives, like imgareaselect, jqCrop and jquery-cropbox (I created and mantain the jquery-cropbox). See here for a very minimal example on how you can get started with one or two lines of jquery.

http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/

- Doing the actual cropping at the client. This requires HTML5, and therefore won't work with older version of internet explorer. In particular you will need the canvas api, and possibly the file api (to serve the files). jquery-cropbox can also do this for you through the `getBlob` and `getDataURL` methods. If you want to do it by hand, take a look here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D

- Uploading the image. There are plenty of scripts for uploading images out there, take your pick. If you are using jquery-cropbox, then you can use jquery to handle the upload to your server like this (uploading client generated form data like this will also require an HTML5 compliant browser).

  ```
  var blob = $('#yourimage').data('cropbox').getBlob();
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', blob);

  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://yourwebsite.com/handle_uploads',
      data: fd,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data){
        alert('upload succeeded');
      },
      error: function () {
        alert('upload failed');
      }
  });
  ```

  },

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following to check filesize on client end:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#image-file').bind('change', function() {
        alert('This file size is: ' + this.files[0].size/1024/1024 + "MB");
    });
</script>
```

If you need a plugin type to use for the entire project you can take a look at [this](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/featuresdemo/index.php).

If you are looking for a multiple uploader please use [this](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Ajax code

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){

    var input = document.getElementById("imagefile");
    var formdata = false;
    if (window.FormData) {
        formdata = new FormData();
    }

    input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {

        var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;

        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            file = this.files[i];

            //validation to check whether uploaded files are images
            if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                if ( window.FileReader ) {
                    reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }


                if (formdata) {
                    //send the ajax query to upload the file(s)
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "upload.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: formdata,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                            jQuery('div#response').html("Successfully uploaded").fadeOut();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Not a vaild image!');
            }   
        }

    }, false);


});
```

HTML Code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="imagefile" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"/ />
</form>
```

What above code will do for you is, once you upload the file(s) it will 1st of validate the type of the image and upload it via ajax for you. You can do **multiple file uploads** if you need. If you ever wonder what `FormData` does,

> The `FormData` object lets you compile a set of key/value pairs to
>   send using XMLHttpRequest. Its primarily intended for use in sending
>   form data, but can be used independently from forms in order to
>   transmit keyed data. The transmitted data is in the same format that
>   the form's submit() method would use to send the data if the form's
>   encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data".

What addEventListener does for you is,

> addEventListener() registers a single event listener on a single
>   target. The event target may be a single element in a document, the
>   document itself, a window, or an XMLHttpRequest.

You can use `upload.php` to upload the file(s) at the server level.

If you want to have the this functionality in a plugin you can extend the plugin with the above code and it will not brick your plugin because this is a very straight forward code snippet which gets the job done. I have successfully integrated the code to a plugin with no issues at all.

this link will show you how to validate for the file size. [JavaScript file upload size validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation)

Re-size it to fit within some particular dimensions
[javascript Image Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170624/javascript-image-resize)

[How to resize images proportionally / keeping the aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio)

These link should help for you. I'm not going to integrate all into one because to maintain the simplicity of the code so you can understand easily.

If you have any issues let me know.

Comment: thanks for the long answer, but if you fully read my question I need to also crop the image as per user's directions, also resize the image(not just on the page but in actual, which you probably misunderstood). So you told me about validating filetype & file size  but that's what I can already achieve with plupload. Also plupload would help me resize the image & reduce quality in actual file so why would I care to build another plugin myself.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this library](http://www.resize-before-upload.com/)

and [this is](http://www.resize-before-upload.com/docs/xml-reference/) documentation page 
where you can set max resize values,

```
<maxwidth>800</maxwidth>
<maxheight>500</maxheight>
<minwidth>100</minwidth>
<minheight>70</minheight>
```

Comment: url is not actual for now, see archive of above http://web.archive.org/web/20121018064239/http://www.resize-before-upload.com/

Answer (score 0):

As for the file type and size:

```
var fileUpload = $(':file[id="fileUploadId"]');
var fileName = $(fileUpload).val();
// Checking type:
if(fileName.indexOf('.jpg') || fileName.indexOf('.gif')){/* Accepted types */}

// Check size
if($(fileUpload).size() <= yourAcceptedSize) {/* Accepted size */}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea.
You can try using this plugin to upload.

http://des.delestesoft.com:8080/?go=2

when you define the attributes: post variables->

```
variables:{
            sessionID:"abcdefg",
            width:$("#myimage").width(),
            height:$("#myimage").heigth()
        },
```

in the server side: you get the file and change the size image according the post variables.

Comment: @learner - please, please, [don't use "this" or "here" as link text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118389/is-there-an-official-position-regarding-text-links-written-as-here-or-this).

Comment: @Olumide - it's bad for, as explained in the linked article. It's bad for visually impaired users, an it is bad UX for the rest of us too. My comment was directed at an editor who's only change was to add the word 'here'