# How to use JavaScript to scale an image to fit

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, scale

I have a 67x67 px image that I would like to scale down to 45x45 to fit into an anchor but I do not know how to adjust it.  My HTML is:

```
<a class="CompareProfilePic" id="CompareProfilePic1" href="#">
   <span id="CompareProfilePicActionBtn1" class="autocenter">
   </span>
</a>
```

My CSS is:

```
a.CompareProfilePic {
   height: 45px;
   width: 45px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px;
   cursor: default !important;
}
```

And my JS is:

```
document.getElementById('CompareProfilePic1').style.cssText = 'background-image: url(img/pic1.jpg)';
```

All my searches led to changing the size of what is holding the image, but that needs to stay 45x45.  Any suggestiosn on how to scale the image to that size?

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look 
[here:](http://jsfiddle.net/a9x1myy6/)

i used

```
document.getElementById('CompareProfilePic1').style.backgroundSize = "45px 45px";
```

Comment: Ah, that is perfect!  Can't believe it is so easy but I could not find that anywhere else.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of using JS, use only CSS with [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)?

```
a.CompareProfilePic {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: default !important;
    background-image: url(img/pic1.jpg);
    background-size: 45px 45px; /*<----*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(this).css('width','px');
 $(this).css('height','auto');
```

answered by this thread on stackoverflow

[javascript Image Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170624/javascript-image-resize)

Comment: whats wrong with this answer? he asked about js, no?